# I am trying to make a little game in python but somethings not working

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is the code:

```
secret_number = 7

guess = input("What number am i thinking of?")

if secret_number == guess:
    print("Yay you got it")
else:
    print("No that's not it")
```

When I run the code I always get "No that's not it" even if I guessed the right number.

Comment: `secret_number = '7'` will make it work. See the difference? Check the documentation of `input` for why this is so.

Comment: `input` returns a string. So the string `'7'` and the number `7` are not equivalent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your input comes in `string` value by default. You have to convert it to `int` in order to work.

`guess =`**`int`**`(input("What number am i thinking of?"))`